# F-Script categories

Tags: categories, f-script

Is there a way to implement the equivalent of the following in F-Script? I can't find any reference to it in the documentation.

```
@implementation SomeClass (SomeCategory)

- (void)doSomething {
    // ...
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support for this in F-Script 2.0. However, this will be supported in the next version.